# Remove records based on criteria

Tags: r

I have three variables a,b and c in dataset P

```
  a b c
  A 1 1
  A 1 2
  A 2 3
  B 4 4
  B 1 5
  B 1 6
  C 2 7
  C 2 8
```

I want to remove records that contain a =A and b=2

I tried below query

```
P <- p[(p$a != "A" & p$b != "2"), ]
```

above is working only for first condition p$a != "A"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are using `&`, get the logical vector where 'a' is equal to 'A', and (`$`) 'b' is equal to 2, negate (`!`) and subset the rows.

```
r1 <- p[!with(p, a=="A" & b==2),]
```

Or use OR  (`|`) instead of `&` in the OP's condition.

```
r2 <- p[with(p, a!="A" | b != 2),]
identical(r1, r2)
#[1] TRUE
```